# Why is my dockerized Django app so slow and shows ([CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT)?

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn, wagtail

I'm trying to deploy a Django app in a Docker container.

It works well but the first time I open a page I receive these messages:

```
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT
[INFO] Worker exiting
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
```

The next time I open the same page it's pretty fast.

Here's my Dockerfile (generated by wagtail app starter)

```
FROM python:3.8.6-slim-buster

RUN useradd wagtail

EXPOSE 8000

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PORT=8000

RUN apt-get update --yes --quiet && apt-get install --yes --quiet --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    libmariadbclient-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    nano \
    vim \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install "gunicorn==20.0.4"

COPY requirements.txt /

RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN chown wagtail:wagtail /app

COPY --chown=wagtail:wagtail . .

USER wagtail

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear

CMD set -xe; python manage.py migrate --noinput; gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: I've implemented that Django + PostGres solution instead: https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/
and it is not happening anymore.